# Add a Jlabel to an existing Jpanel

Tags: java

Hi I'm trying to add a JLabel or a `JCheckBox` on an existing `JPanel` depending on the selection of a radio button when I push a button, here's my code so far:

```
package GUI;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author ipodi
 */

public class Note extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public Note() {
    initComponents();
    Options.add(rBtNote);
    Options.add(rBtCheck);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    Entries.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
}

private int noLabel = 0;
private int noCheck = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void initComponents() {

    Options = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    info = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel5 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel6 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    rBtNote = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    rBtCheck = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    Entries = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    OpenMenu = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    SaveMenu = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jSeparator3 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
    Exit = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    About = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 450));

    jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    info.setText("jLabel1");
    jPanel3.add(info);

    jPanel1.add(jPanel3, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    jPanel5.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

    jButton2.setText("Add Entry");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    rBtNote.setText("Note");

    rBtCheck.setText("Check list");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel6Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel6);
    jPanel6.setLayout(jPanel6Layout);
    jPanel6Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(rBtNote)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(rBtCheck)
                            .addGap(102, 102, 102)
                            .addComponent(jButton2))
                        .addComponent(jTextField1))
                    .addGap(42, 42, 42))))
    );
    jPanel6Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel6Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(rBtNote)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel6Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(rBtCheck)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    jPanel5.add(jPanel6, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    jPanel5.add(Entries, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    getContentPane().add(jPanel5, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    OpenMenu.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_O, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    OpenMenu.setText("Open...");
    jMenu1.add(OpenMenu);

    jMenu3.setText("Recent Notes");
    jMenu1.add(jMenu3);
    jMenu1.add(jSeparator2);

    SaveMenu.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    SaveMenu.setText("Save Note");
    jMenu1.add(SaveMenu);
    jMenu1.add(jSeparator3);

    Exit.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F4, java.awt.event.InputEvent.ALT_MASK));
    Exit.setText("Exit Note");
    Exit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ExitActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(Exit);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("About");

    About.setText("About");
    jMenu2.add(About);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void ExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    Selection S = new Selection();
    if (SaveMenu.isEnabled() == true) {
        int opt = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Do you want to save the changes on the Note?", "Alert", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (opt == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "YEY!!");
            S.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        } else if (opt == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            S.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    } else {
        S.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
}                                    

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (jTextField1.getText().length() < 4) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please set a word with minumum of 4 characters.");
    } else {
        int bug = 0;
        if (rBtNote.isSelected()) {
            noLabel++;
            JLabel label = new JLabel(jTextField1.getText());
            Entries.add(label);
            label.setName("jl" + noLabel);
            rBtNote.setSelected(false);
        } else if (rBtCheck.isSelected()) {
            noCheck++;
            JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox(jTextField1.getText(), false);
            Entries.add(check);
            check.setName("ch" + noCheck);
            rBtCheck.setSelected(false);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please select an option.");
        }
    }
}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Selection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Selection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Selection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Selection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Selection().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private javax.swing.JMenuItem About;
private javax.swing.JPanel Entries;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Exit;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem OpenMenu;
private javax.swing.ButtonGroup Options;
private javax.swing.JMenuItem SaveMenu;
private javax.swing.JLabel info;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel6;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator2;
private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator3;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton rBtCheck;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton rBtNote;
```

}

I know is all the code but well still the error is in this area:

```
if (jTextField1.getText().length() < 4) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please set a word with minumum of 4 characters.");
    } else {
        int bug = 0;
        if (rBtNote.isSelected()) {
            noLabel++;
            JLabel label = new JLabel(jTextField1.getText());
            Entries.add(label);
            label.setName("jl" + noLabel);
            rBtNote.setSelected(false);
        } else if (rBtCheck.isSelected()) {
            noCheck++;
            JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox(jTextField1.getText(), false);
            Entries.add(check);
            check.setName("ch" + noCheck);
            rBtCheck.setSelected(false);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please select an option.");
        }
    }
}
```

and when I run it there is no error but it doesn't show it on the `JFrame` nor `JPanel`.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: what is the layout of the container ? did u call `revalidate()` `reapint()` methods ?

Comment: check if it is invoking the action listener or a change listener on `rBtNote` or `rBCheck`

Comment: Which layout did you use in your JPanel? I think that is the issue.

Comment: We can't tell without the type declaration of `Entries`, and I highly recommend that if `Entries` is not a static method call, consider making it lower case.  In most cases, adding a widget to a container is not enough anyway, you typically have to re-layout the widget by calling `revalidate()`

Comment: It does work with `revalidate()` thank you